# Why do structured bindings depend on tuple_element?

Tags: c++, c++17, structured-bindings

The [most recent draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0144r2.pdf) of the structured bindings proposal (on which the C++17 feature was based) requires `std::tuple_size`, member `get` or `std::get`, and `std::tuple_element`. [Previous drafts](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0144r1.pdf) require only `std::tuple_size` and member `get` or `std::get`. As far as I can tell, there was no discussion on adding this, it just appeared in the final draft. Is there a compelling reason to require the `tuple_element` specialization, considering I believe it can be implemented in general as

```
template<std::size_t index, typename T>
struct tuple_element {
    using type = decltype(std::get<index>(std::declval<T>()));
};
```

Does anyone know of why this requirement was added?

Comment: This might be needed for perfect forwarding,  `std::get` returns `std::tuple_element_t<I, tuple<Types...> >&` or `std::tuple_element_t<I, tuple<Types...> >&&`

Comment: Your implementation is broken. For example, `std::get` returns a reference type with `std::tuple` regardless if the element is a reference or not. Worse, the reference depends on the value category of the `std::tuple`

Comment: I think it should be `get` instead of `std::get` in your implementation to make use of ADL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the case:

```
std::tuple<int, int&>& foo();
auto& [x, y] = foo();
```

What is `decltype(x)` and what is `decltype(y)`? The goal of the language feature is that `x` just be another name for `foo().__0` and `y` be another name for `foo().__1`, which means that they should to be `int` and `int&`, respectively. As specificied today, this unpacks into<sup>†</sup>:

```
auto& __e = foo();
std::tuple_element_t<0, decltype(__e)>& x = std::get<0>(__e);
std::tuple_element_t<1, decltype(__e)>& y = std::get<1>(__e);
```

And the rules work such that `decltype(x)` is the type to which `x` *refers*, so `int`. And `decltype(y)` is the type to which `y` *refers*, so `int&`.

If we avoided `tuple_element`, by doing something like:

```
auto&& x = std::get<0>(__e);
auto&& y = std::get<1>(__e);
```

Then we couldn't differentiate between `x` and `y`, because there is no way to differentiate between what `std::get<0>(__e)` and `std::get<1>(__e)` do: both give back an `int&`.

This is also the way to add consistency between the above case and the normal struct case:

```
struct C {
    int i;
    int& r;
};
C& bar();
auto& [a, b] = bar();
```

We want, for the purposes of structured bindings, for `a` and `b` here to behave the same way as `x` and `y` there. And `a` and `b` here aren't introduced variables, they're just different names for `__e.i` and `__e.r`.

---

In the non-reference case, there is a different scenario where we cannot differentiate:

```
std::tuple<int, int&&> foo();
auto [x, y] = foo();
```

Here, we at present unpack via:

```
auto __e = foo();
std::tuple_element_t<0, decltype(e)>& x = std::get<0>(std::move(__e));
std::tuple_element_t<1, decltype(e)>& y = std::get<1>(std::move(__e));
```

Both `std::get` calls return an `int&&`, so you couldn't differentiate between them using `auto&&`... but the results of `tuple_element_t` are different - `int` and `int&&`, respectively. This difference *could* be seen with the normal struct case too.

---

<sup>†</sup>Note that due to [CWG 2313](https://wg21.link/cwg2313), actually the unpacking happens into a uniquely named variable reference and the identifiers specified into the binding just refer to those objects.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't unpack into what you said. It used to be like that, but after a DR it changed to what you're saying, but the variables are `__x` and `__y` (or whatever) and `x` and `y` refer to the object bound to those variables. Just to be pedantic :)

Comment: [CWG 2313](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2313) for the curious. I think I'll keep the answer as-is, I think it at least conveys the idea @Rakete1111

Comment: `decltype(x)` is also `int&` in your first example.

Comment: @Barry Oh sorry, I mean `x` in `std::tuple_element_t<0, decltype(__e)>& x = std::get<0>(__e);`.

Comment: @xskxzr Yeah, that's just exposition, but I'm assuming we're still following the same rules as to how to determine what `decltype(x)` means.

Comment: For your example `__e` is actually cast to an xvalue for `get`, so you can differentiate `int` and `int&` from the return type of `get` - but not `int` and `int&&`.